# How to provide attribution when numerous contributors hold copyright

Tags: mit, copyright, attribution

My software depends on and links to a third-party open-source library licensed under the MIT license. No copyright notice is present in the LICENSE file, the README file, or any of the source files. However, my understanding is that [all contributors to such projects are copyright holders](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/2a8807e889a43c6b89eb6f2736907afa87ae592f), and that the MIT license requires reproduction of its copyright notice even if it's [implicit](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/license-but-no-copyright-notice-how-to-attribute-correctly).

How might I provide attribution to such a third-party library? Would it be sufficient to have a copyright notice like "Copyright (c) the CoolLibrary contributors" or would I need to list out every contributor individually even when there are dozens (or more) of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the question you linked to, the MIT license requires that you preserve the existing copyright notices. It does not require that you add/invent any missing copyright notices.

If you are just linking to the library and you are reproducing the licensing information for the documentation of your binary-only distribution, then you can just write something like

> This software uses CoolLibrary, which is under the MIT license.
>
> <MIT license text>

without adding copyright notices.

If you copy code under the MIT license, which doesn't have any copyright notices, into your project, then it might be a good idea to add a copyright line like `Copyright (c) the CoolLibrary authors` to make it abundantly clear that the copyright line that follows with your name on it doesn't claim the copyrights for the whole file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If I were to add the missing copyright notice to the documentation of my binary-only distribution, would it be okay to use `Copyright (c) the CoolLibrary authors` there too? Or would it be better if I didn't try to add/invent the missing notice?

Comment: @toomuchfanservice, it would be better not to invent the missing notice, as there is no chance that another copyright notice gives the wrong impression.